# JQ изменение в двух блоках с одинаковым id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите почему не работает, у меня на странице 2 id со значением к примеру test. Следующий код меняет только первое значение блока, почему, как поменять сразу 2?

```
$('#test').text(deliveryCost);
```

Comment: ID может быть только один на странице! Точнее в одной области.

Comment: используйте разные id, или используйте class

Comment: Увы даже google лоббирует стандарт с уникальным ID - начал выдавать ошибки в консоли. Поэтому лучше от греха, не дублировать ID. Тем не менее на практике это бывает сложно - например заказчик захотел вывести несколько существующих форм(которые раньше были на своих страницах) - в одной странице: а тратить своё время на лабуду программисты не любят, если всё работает и так :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Селектор по id выдает только первый найденный элемент.

Не рекомендуется использовать элементы с идентичными id, однако если уж очень хочется, то есть такой хак: использовать Attribute Equals selector вместо id selector.

```js
$('button').on('click',magic);
function magic(){
$('[id="test"]').text('clicked!!!');
}
```

```css
.test1{
color:blue;
}
.test2{
color:violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='test' class='test1'>test1</div>
<div id='test' class='test2'>test2</div>
<button>Магия</button>
```

Comment: В тему: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/127178